# Benefits of hstore over a key/value table with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

In one of our applications, we need to have some key/value pairs that we will periodically update.

We initially thought about a table which would be something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "KeyValue" (
    "Key"   TEXT UNIQUE,
    "Value" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Key")
);
```

Which perfectly fits our needs.

But while digging if there was something already builtin I found out about the [`hstore` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/hstore.html), but I can't really get my head around about the benefits of using that hstore instead of my old-fashion table.

In addition the syntax seems a bit weird to me, when looking at examples I can't find a simple example where it would be explained how to create a pair (e.g. `"StartDate": "2012/12/25"`), read it (e.g. `"2012/12/25"`), then update it (`"StartDate": "2012/12/26"`), and potentially delete it.

Is there someone who could explain the benefits of using the `hstore` approach over the traditional table I just made up above?

Comment: `hstore` (or `jsonb` in modern Postgres versions) is typically used if you want to attach dynamic key/value pairs to an existing table. If you just have key/value pairs without a relation to an existing table, your table is probably more efficient as you can update individual keys without rewriting all the others

Comment: Unrelated, but: [avoid](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) those dreaded quoted identifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used `hstore` previously through Hibernate/Java way back. I did it because *the total size of the per row map was small*, but the table like you describe it with row specific key-value pairs would had had really many rows. I might be mistaken but I recall the `hstore` may have originally been designed for small maps but there is no longer mention of such in the documentation pages. Also, my requirements for the hstore column were only related to the row, any "reporting" which was done for all of the column values was for development only.

Though, looking at your example table, it would appear you are looking for *globally unique* keys where as I think `hstore` is most useful when you have one `hstore` per row. I don't think you should solve the "globally unique keys" with a hstore and some index while it's possible you could.

Note that you linked to an unsupported version of the postgresql, here's the latest [`hstore` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html). It does have examples of instantiation (`SELECT 'a=>1,a=>2'::hstore;` or `hstore('c', '3')`) and [the examples section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#id-1.11.7.25.7) contains the rest of the examples you asked.

It's been a while since I last developed or maintained anything on postgresql, but what I remember, the [`json`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) support was coming up fast and looked interesting. If you are storing anything except opaque strings in your `Value` column, it might be worth your while to look at the json support as it can support [the json datatypes with some limitations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-TYPE-MAPPING-TABLE).

Comment: Thanks for [a horse with no name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) for fixing that documentation link to current. Apparently SO has no optimistic concurrency checking when accepting edits to answers :)